# git lfs fails to track a file after I rename it

Tags: git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

I keep running into this issue where I rename a file that is being tracked under git lfs, and when I push up the change to my repo, the file is no longer being tracked by git lfs.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `git add --renormalize .` resolves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I erased the line of the file from `.gitattributes` and then ran `git lfs track <new_file_path>`